# Buttons don't get disabled in java

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have created a button.. I want that whenever I click on the button it first disable the other two buttons and then do other tasks that I have programmed .. but it disable the buttons at the end

```
Extract.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

Button1.setEnabled(false);

Button2.setEnabled(false);

obj.showData(); 

obj.extractClassesPackagesImports();

obj.inheritanceRelation();

obj.doubleinheritanceRelation();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");

}

});
```

Now the above program disable the buttons after showing the message box..
can anyone figure out what's wrong here... thanks in advance

Comment: what is your error, i can't understand what you want to achieve. Consider making a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)

Comment: I understand that the buttons are disabled when showing a message box, not when the button is clicked. But I don't know what is `Extract` here (the OP should show more code). by the way, this variable name should begin a lower case letter, like the other variables names.

Comment: It sounds like you are not allowing the GUI thread time to update in the time before you show the dialog box. I'm not sure what is the best way to "yield" and allow swing to update the gui - perhaps `invokeLater` - does anyone know?

Comment: @Arnaud Denoyelle Considering the question it looks like Extract is a Jbutton object. I'm updating the question to add this information.

Comment: unrelated: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 1):

As @vikingsteve said, your most likely not allowing the GUI thread time to update the dialog.

If you add `Thread.Sleep(1000);` you will certainly see a delay between the disabling and the messagebox.

I don't understand though the utility of why it makes a difference whether the buttons are disabled before or after the dialog.

**Update**

I have added an additional Thread, in order to be able to utilize Thread.sleep(5000) , without freezing the Event Dispatching Thread (GUI) completely.

However, since now my code is calling showMessageDialog from a new Thread, I should make use of invokeLater.

Additionally, since the original code will allow the user to click buttons even though we are waiting for activities to finish, I believe all actions should be moved to a separate thread like this:

```
Extract.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                //Disable Buttons since we are in Event Dispatching Thread
                Button1.setEnabled(false);
                Button2.setEnabled(false);

                //Tasks moved to separate Thread
                 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                //Perform Tasks
                                obj.showData();
                                obj.extractClassesPackagesImports();
                                obj.inheritanceRelation();
                                obj.doubleinheritanceRelation();

                                //Delay before calling message (we are delaying in separate thread to not freeze GUI completely)
                                Thread.sleep(5000); 
                                //Wait 5 seconds before showing dialog

                                //Show the GUI - since GUI interaction from new Thread using invokeLater
                                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");
                                    }
                                });

                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }                         
                        }
                    }).start();     

            }
        });
```

The above code adds a delay before displaying a message, while also not freezing the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");
    }
});
```

Comment: Your calling invokeLater when your already on the Event dispatch thread? If I understand correctly isn't this like taking the bus to go where you already are?

Comment: Calling invokeLater should allow the gui updates to be processed before showing the dialog.

Comment: @meewoK That way, the action inside the `Runnable` is queued to be executed *after the current code*, instead of executing it on the spot.

Comment: Should is a very indefinite term. While running your code it executes so quickly that it is not the case. If not much else is happening in the GUI we're talking minimal delay (in the MS range).

Comment: @vikingsteve likely you want all the code after the two calls to setEnable(false) to be called with SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). The op probably wants to see the buttons disabled right after those two calls. (Doing so will still block the entire GUI for the duration, but the buttons will show as disabled)

Comment: @nos ok, thanks. waiting now to see if this all works for op :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at code from `AbstractButton`, `JComponent`, and `RepaintManager`, I conclude that `setEnabled()` posts a new event on the event queue, to display the disabled button.
Thus, looking at your code, the following events happen, as you describe:

```
EventQueue:
    Event1: {
        setEnabled(false) // queues Event2
        showMessageDialog(null, "Done")
    },
    Event2: {
        repaint() // to display the disabled button
    }
```

The relevant code is given below:

**AbstractButton**

```
public void setEnabled(boolean b) {
    // ...
    super.setEnabled(b);
    // ...
}
```

**JComponent**

```
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    // ...
    if (enabled != oldEnabled) {
        repaint();
    }
}

public void repaint(long tm, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    RepaintManager.currentManager(this).addDirtyRegion(this, x, y, width, height);
}
```

**RepaintManager**

```
public void addDirtyRegion(JComponent c, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    // ...
    addDirtyRegion0(c, x, y, w, h);
}

private void addDirtyRegion0(Container c, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    // ...

    // Queue a Runnable to invoke paintDirtyRegions and
    // validateInvalidComponents.
    scheduleProcessingRunnable();
}
```

---

If you want the button to be displayed as disabled *before* you show the dialog, the solution, as @vikingsteve pointed out, is to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

```
extract.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        button1.setEnabled(false);
        button2.setEnabled(false);
        obj.showData(); 
        obj.extractClassesPackagesImports();
        obj.inheritanceRelation();
        obj.doubleinheritanceRelation();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that showing the dialog using SwingUtilities.invokeLater is not going to help. The long running operation probably obj.extractClassesPackagesImports(); So while the first 2 lines of code disables the button, this is not going to show in the GUI until the last line (JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");) is executed. JOptionPane will run the GUI event loop(so no need for invokeLater), so the buttons will update when the JOptionPane is shown. The OP probably wants to see the buttons disabled right after the setEnabled(false) is called.

Comment: @nos Indeed, the operations on `obj` may take a while, so I'd say they should probably be run on another thread, calling a method that displays the dialog in the EDT when done.